# WHERE clause on Multiple type of Join query

Tags: mysql

I'm having problems with a MySQL Query. I have read a lot of the currently answered threads, following a lot of examples but I have not been able to solve my trouble so I come to you for help. Thanks in advance.

I have this query:

```
SELECT ventas.*,
clientes.nombre AS CLIENT_NOMBRE,
clientes.telefono AS TELEFONO,
users.nombre AS USERNAME,
canales_ventas.nombre AS CAN_VENTA,
estados_venta.nombre AS ESTADOS,
metodos_pago.nombre AS MET_PAGO,
canales_entrega.nombre AS CAN_ENTREGA,
canales_entrega.categoria AS CAN_ENTREGA_CAT,
COALESCE(perc.qty,0) AS DESC_PERCENT,
COALESCE(fix.qty,0) AS DESC_FIXED,
COALESCE(SUM(ventas_productos.vp_cantidad*ventas_productos.vp_precio),0) AS Total_Value
FROM ventas
JOIN clientes ON clientes.id = ventas.cliente_id 
JOIN users ON users.id = ventas.vendedor_id 
LEFT OUTER JOIN canales_ventas ON canales_ventas.id = ventas.canal_venta_id 
LEFT OUTER JOIN estados_venta ON estados_venta.id = ventas.estado_actual 
LEFT OUTER JOIN metodos_pago ON metodos_pago.id = ventas.metodo_pago
LEFT OUTER JOIN canales_entrega ON canales_entrega.id = ventas.metodo_entrega
LEFT OUTER JOIN ventas_descuentos perc ON perc.orden_id = ventas.id AND perc.tipo = 1
LEFT OUTER JOIN ventas_descuentos fix ON fix.orden_id = ventas.id AND fix.tipo = 2
LEFT JOIN ventas_productos ON ventas_productos.vp_orden_id = ventas.id GROUP BY ventas.id
```

But I need that all the results match `ventas.estado_actual = 7`

I'd appreciate a lot the help. Thanks!

EDIT1:
I have tried Using WHERE in these ways:

After the last Join:

```
SELECT ventas.*,
clientes.nombre AS CLIENT_NOMBRE,
clientes.telefono AS TELEFONO,
users.nombre AS USERNAME,
canales_ventas.nombre AS CAN_VENTA,
estados_venta.nombre AS ESTADOS,
metodos_pago.nombre AS MET_PAGO,
canales_entrega.nombre AS CAN_ENTREGA,
canales_entrega.categoria AS CAN_ENTREGA_CAT,
COALESCE(perc.qty,0) AS DESC_PERCENT,
COALESCE(fix.qty,0) AS DESC_FIXED,
COALESCE(SUM(ventas_productos.vp_cantidad*ventas_productos.vp_precio),0) AS Total_Value
FROM ventas
JOIN clientes ON clientes.id = ventas.cliente_id 
JOIN users ON users.id = ventas.vendedor_id 
LEFT OUTER JOIN canales_ventas ON canales_ventas.id = ventas.canal_venta_id 
LEFT OUTER JOIN estados_venta ON estados_venta.id = ventas.estado_actual 
LEFT OUTER JOIN metodos_pago ON metodos_pago.id = ventas.metodo_pago
LEFT OUTER JOIN canales_entrega ON canales_entrega.id = ventas.metodo_entrega
LEFT OUTER JOIN ventas_descuentos perc ON perc.orden_id = ventas.id AND perc.tipo = 1
LEFT OUTER JOIN ventas_descuentos fix ON fix.orden_id = ventas.id AND fix.tipo = 2
LEFT JOIN ventas_productos ON ventas_productos.vp_orden_id = ventas.id GROUP BY ventas.id
WHERE ventas.estado_actual = 7

ERROR #1064 - Something is wrong in your syntax 'LIMIT 0, 25' on line 23
```

In the From Clause:

```
SELECT ventas.*,
clientes.nombre AS CLIENT_NOMBRE,
clientes.telefono AS TELEFONO,
users.nombre AS USERNAME,
canales_ventas.nombre AS CAN_VENTA,
estados_venta.nombre AS ESTADOS,
metodos_pago.nombre AS MET_PAGO,
canales_entrega.nombre AS CAN_ENTREGA,
canales_entrega.categoria AS CAN_ENTREGA_CAT,
COALESCE(perc.qty,0) AS DESC_PERCENT,
COALESCE(fix.qty,0) AS DESC_FIXED,
COALESCE(SUM(ventas_productos.vp_cantidad*ventas_productos.vp_precio),0) AS Total_Value
FROM ventas WHERE ventas.estado_actual = 7
JOIN clientes ON clientes.id = ventas.cliente_id 
JOIN users ON users.id = ventas.vendedor_id 
LEFT OUTER JOIN canales_ventas ON canales_ventas.id = ventas.canal_venta_id 
LEFT OUTER JOIN estados_venta ON estados_venta.id = ventas.estado_actual 
LEFT OUTER JOIN metodos_pago ON metodos_pago.id = ventas.metodo_pago
LEFT OUTER JOIN canales_entrega ON canales_entrega.id = ventas.metodo_entrega
LEFT OUTER JOIN ventas_descuentos perc ON perc.orden_id = ventas.id AND perc.tipo = 1
LEFT OUTER JOIN ventas_descuentos fix ON fix.orden_id = ventas.id AND fix.tipo = 2
LEFT JOIN ventas_productos ON ventas_productos.vp_orden_id = ventas.id GROUP BY ventas.id 

ERROR - #1064 Again the same error
```

Comment: Why not a `WHERE` clause: `WHERE ventas.estado_actual = 7`

Comment: Edited Answer showing how I've tried using Where clause

Comment: The `Group-by` should be after the `where` clause and I know my eyesight needs help but I can't see a `limit` clause in your sql

Comment: Thanks Professor Abronsius! that was the problem! Is there a problem with not having a limit clause?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

where clause must be before group by

```
WHERE ventas.estado_actual = 7 GROUP BY ventas.id
```